Adding months to a date field in SQLite
I'm trying to add 3 months to a field which contains date value by running the below query:
SELECT  [Date Created], DATE([Date Created], '+3 month') AS 'Date Created (+ X Months)'
FROM WARRANTY_PN_MISSING_COMPATIBILITY_TABLE

Something seems to be wrong in fact this is the final result:

Please, can you help me on fixing the query?
Thanks
Fixing the query

SQLite has no date type. How are the dates actually stored? Date strings must be in ISO8601 format ie YYYY-MM-DD....

SQLite does not support the datetime format you're using according to the screenshot. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#time_values.

Dear all, thanks for your feedback. Date is written in this format m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss while the field is formatted as DATETIME

As @PanagiotisKanavos pointed out in the comments. your date format is not in the correct format for Sqlite to accept it as vaild date. With that said the solution would be to reformat the string into a vaild format. If possible I would recommend using the application, that saves the data, if that is not possible and you could do the conversion in a select query, something like this:
(in this example it's the date column)
SELECT 
    DATE( 
        SUBSTR(date , INSTR(SUBSTR(date, 4), '/') + 4, 4)  -- gets the year
        || '-' || 
        IIF(LENGTH (SUBSTR(date , 0,  INSTR(date, '/')) ) = 1, '0', '') || -- adds a leading Zero if needed
        SUBSTR(date , 0,  INSTR(date, '/')) -- gets the months 
        || '-' || 
        IIF(LENGTH(RTRIM(SUBSTR(date ,  INSTR(date, '/') + 1, 2) , '/') )= 1, '0', '') ||-- adds a leading Zero if needed
        RTRIM(SUBSTR(date ,  INSTR(date, '/') + 1, 2) , '/')  -- gets the days
        || SUBSTR(date , INSTR(date, ' ')) -- gets the time
        , '3 months') cleanDate
 FROM test ;


It's not elegant or performant, but it should work in your case, where the stored date format is "m/d/y 00:00:00". (if the time-part has some missing leading zeros this could be an issue )


Looking at your comments I have converted the format date I have on my SQLite DB from m/dd/yyyy 00:00:00 to the accepted one yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and the below queries seems to be working now:
SELECT  [Date Created], DATETIME([Date Created], '+3 month') AS 'Date
Created (+ X Months)' FROM WARRANTY_PN_MISSING_COMPATIBILITY_TABLE
 
UPDATE WARRANTY_PN_MISSING_COMPATIBILITY_TABLE  SET "Date Created (+ X
Months)" = DATETIME("Date Created", '+3 months')

Nota:
Date value on my SQLite DB are stored in a field defined as DATETIME
